# Hiding RefreshControl in Android React Native

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I have a requirement where I want to hide the refresh indicator completely of Refresh Control for Android. I already set most of the color properties to transparent by still see gray circular indicator. Is there any way to completely hide this circular indicator. Link to gif about what is hapenning: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aICIV.jpg

This is my code:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  TextInput,
  View,
  FlatList,
  Dimensions,
  RefreshControl,
  ToastAndroid,
} from 'react-native';


import Constants from './Constants';



export default class TestList extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.rows =[{id: 1},{id: 2},{id: 3},{id: 4}];
    this.state = {
      refreshing: false,
    }
  }


  renderItem(row) {
    return (
      <Text style={{fontSize: 20, borderBottomWidth: 1, borderColor: 'red', color: 'blue', height:80}}>{row.item.id}</Text>
      )
    }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={[styles.container]}>
        <FlatList
          data={this.rows}
          renderItem={this.renderItem.bind(this)}
          overScrollMode='always'
          style={{flex: 1}}
          keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
          removeClippedSubviews={false}
          keyboardShouldPersistTaps='always'
          refreshControl={
            <RefreshControl
              colors={['transparent']}
              style={{backgroundColor: 'transparent'}}
              progressBackgroundColor='transparent'
              refreshing={this.state.refreshing}
              onRefresh={() =>
              ToastAndroid.show('Refresh completed with short duration', ToastAndroid.SHORT)}/>}
          ref="FlatList"/>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
})


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aICIV.jpg
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Platform` api from react native.

```
import { Platform } from 'react-native'

<Flatlist
  ...other props
  refreshControl={
    Platform.select({
     ios: (
       <RefreshControl
          colors={['transparent']}
          style={{backgroundColor: 'transparent'}}
          progressBackgroundColor='transparent'
          refreshing={this.state.refreshing}
          onRefresh={() =>
            ToastAndroid.show(
             'Refresh completed with short duration',
             ToastAndroid.SHORT
            )
          }
       />
     )
    })
  }
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and wanted the same thing, but did not get it for android, so I tried the prop. progressViewOffset={number}, up-to such that the pull to refresh worked as well as the loading icon was hidden(was above the view). This is not proper solution but it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You could conditionally render the RefreshControl component so that it only renders when you want it to.

The react docs discuss some techniques here: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/conditional-rendering.html

But for simplicity's sake, I prefer to use the https://github.com/ajwhite/render-if npm module to conditionally render the component based on a flag in your component's state or in a redux store.

Answer (score -2):

This works for me on iOS (have not tested on Android):

```
refreshControl={
  <RefreshControl
      refreshing={false}
      onRefresh={this.onRefreshHandler.bind(this)}
      title='Pull to refresh'
      tintColor='transparent'
   />
}
```

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: Hmm ... from what I recall setting `refreshing={false}` prevents the view from indicating an active refresh. The question was to hide the refresh indicator.

Comment: Question is specifically for Android, which is apparently the harder question. I appreciate the time you took to type though.